# Repositary for Pagination in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fetching around 10,000 records from a service. I need to implement pagination in my ASP.NET UI. I don't want to store the records in the database. I have planned to fetch records in chunk (of 100 records) and put them in cache.

If I display 10 records/page, then I can paginate between 10 pages. Now if a user clicks page number 11, then again I will call the service, get the records and refresh the cache to hold a new set of records. If a user again clicks on the first page index, I need to hit the service again.

Is this a feasible strategy for pagination in an ASP.NET context? Also, too many records in cache could impact on performance. Could anybody suggest an effective approach for this kind of scenario?

Comment: its perfect!!! but why u cached data? I see no benefit here.

Comment: You can create wrapper for your service calls to do caching.

Answer (score 0):

If using Pagination there is no reason to cache. Otherwise this is generally the right approach.

Flow is select (select from) -> filter (where) -> sort (orderby) -> skip(page * pagesize) -> take(pagesize).

This should ALL get passed down to the data layer such that the user code is not actually executing any of it, the db is. The skip/take part is usually where people have the most issues as it requires a generate column in the query (row number) but is usually doable on the DB side.